# How to run an awk script on a certain file without putting the file name when i run the program

Tags: awk

Is it possible to make an awk program to run on a file without giving it 
the name of the file when you run the program.

i tried to do this but for some reason it does not work,can someone please explain
why this does not work and how do i make it work

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
ARGV[1]="books"
}
{
split($0,a,":")
if(a[4]!="-"){
n[a[2]]=n[a[2]]+1
print $0","n[a[2]]
}
}
END{
for(x in n){
print n[x]
}
}
```

in this program i tried to make it run on a file name books but it still does not work

Comment: You may have to write a wrapper script that invokes awk with your script and a filename.

Comment: is it the only way?

Answer (score 5):

As well as adding an element to `ARGV`, you need to increment `ARGC`:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
  ARGV[1]="books"
  ++ARGC
}
```

From the [GNU AWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html):

> Storing additional elements [in `ARGV`] and incrementing `ARGC` causes additional files to be read.